# In Chrome Extension, change referrer for ajax requests sent to certain domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've done some research and I now know it's not possible to send a request with a changed referrer in Google Chrome because the browser will overwrite the change, but is there anyway/any permissions in a Google Chrome Extension that would disable this, or make it so that you could send a request to a certain domain with a different referrer?

Comment: Lets say its possible, how would you handle this, ask users to change their Chrome settings?

Comment: It's for personal use, I simply want to be able to send a request from a certain referrer

Comment: Is it perhaps possible, however, to change the browser settings to not overwrite the referrer? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) is what you're looking for, specifically thee `onBeforeSendHeaders` event. It will allow you to change any headers (even unsafe ones) before sending the request, but can only be used in a background script.

You'll need to add `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` to your permissions list in the manifest.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addEventListener(handle(details), filterObject, extraInfoArray);
```

Here's an example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    var newRef = "http://referer.domain/helloworld.example";
    var gotRef = false;
    for(var n in details.requestHeaders){
        gotRef = details.requestHeaders[n].name.toLowerCase()=="referer";
        if(gotRef){
            details.requestHeaders[n].value = newRef;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!gotRef){
        details.requestHeaders.push({name:"Referer",value:newRef});
    }
    return {requestHeaders:details.requestHeaders};
},{
    urls:["http://target.domain/*"]
},[
    "requestHeaders",
    "blocking",
    "extraHeaders"
]);
```

The `filterObject` tells it to only fire the handle for any with the urls matching ones in the list.

The `extraInfoArray` tells it you want to get `requestHeaders`, and `blocking` tells it to pause the request until the handle is finished.

Comment: As of chrome 72 "extraHeaders" must also be added to extraInfoArray in order to set the following headers: Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Referer, Cookie

Comment: I have implement this code and console in background.js which reflect the changed referrer, but how can i check same in  page when opens developers tool or clicked on some link.

Comment: I pasted the above code (with mentioned permissions) in my `background.js` file as it is. Just changed the `target_urls`. This does not work. Also, I cannot set background `persistent` to `false`, as it does not run on event pages. Have to set it to `true` to make it run.

Any help on this please.

Answer (score 4):

now in manifest v3 `webRequestBlocking` is no more there .. instead create a rule to dynamically set the referrer  [ref](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#method-updateDynamicRules)

permission:

```
"permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ]
```

in backgroud script

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    addRules: [{
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "modifyHeaders",
            "requestHeaders": [
                { "header": "Referer", "operation": "set", "value": "htts://targetHost" }
            ]
        },
        "condition": {
            "urlFilter": "https://condidtionUrl",
            "resourceTypes": ["xmlhttprequest"] // see available https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-ResourceType
        }
    }],
})
```

operation `apend` having some know bugs [ref](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1117475)  instead use `set`