# Referer header is no longer sent by Chrome Beta (71.0.3578.30)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

I need to set `Referer` header in a request of my Chrome extension.

I implemented this in my background script using the answer from [In Chrome Extension, change referrer for ajax requests sent to certain domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999159)

It worked earlier, but now `Referer` tag is not sent (Chrome Beta **71**.0.3578.30 x64 on Windows).  I've checked it using Fiddler. Though the header is still there in `onSendHeaders` callback.

```
on_send_headers = function flx_on_send_headers (details) {
    console.log(details.requestHeaders);
    return null;
};

chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(on_send_headers, ({urls: ["https://www.sitename.com/*"]}), ["requestHeaders"]);
```

Any other headers ('test1', 'xReferer' etc.) can be added and sent successfully.

On another machine I have Chrome **70**.0.3538.77 x64, it works as expected.

Comment: Check if it's reported on [crbug.com](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=referer&sort=-modified).

Comment: @wOxxOm maybe [this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=827582) I'm not sure.

Comment: I also encounter this issue since a few days, Chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `extraHeaders` solved the issue for me.

> Starting from Chrome 72, the following request headers are not
>   provided and cannot be modified or removed without specifying
>   '**extraHeaders**' in opt_extraInfoSpec.

source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest