# Change referer in extension with chrome.webrequest.onBeforeSendHeaders

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a persistent background script that looks something like this that I am attempting to use to change the referer of a XmlHttpRequest being sent by my extension popup:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
  var headers = details.requestHeaders;
  if(details.initiator.startsWith("chrome-extension")){
      headers.push({"name":"Referer", "value":"https://example1.com"})
  }
  let ret = {requestHeaders: headers}
  console.log(ret)
  return ret;
},
{urls: [ "https://*.example2.com/*" ]},['requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders']);
```

The code works insofar as the console.log shows a valid set of headers with the referer set, but when I actually look at the request from the chrome inspector it doesn't show a referer. Why might this be the case?

Comment: There's probably an existing header in the array, which you need to find and remove first.

Comment: If you want to modify the headers, beside `'requestHeaders'` and `'extraHeaders'` you also need `'blocking'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999159/in-chrome-extension-change-referrer-for-ajax-requests-sent-to-certain-domain.